# Testing the autocorrelation's significance without having its value

Tags: autocorrelation, residuals

[image: Results of OLS regression in]

I'm getting confused with an exercice my teacher gave me. I am supposed to perform a test for the presence of autocorrelation in the innovations of the model with a significance level of 10%.

Under innovations I understand the factors SMB and HML; but I don't see a way of calculating their autocorrelation coefficients, to eventually then perform a Box-Pierce test.

Another solution would then probably be to try to obtain the autocorrelation of residuals, and see if these are significant or not. But again I have no clue on how to calculate these. I am probably missing something out here. Please tell me if you have any idea on how to proceed.

Additional information: Sample size 84, R2adjusted 0.025

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: In a time series setting, innovations or shocks are the same as model errors. This is not the same as regressors. So innovations are neither SMB nor HML.